# How to get the current behave step with Python?

Tags: python, python-behave

I'm using behave with Python to do my tests. In the step file, I want to get the current step name, because if the test fails, I take a screenshot and rename the file to the step name.

Something like this:

**Given** user is logged in
**When** user does something
**Then** something happens

And I wanted my step code to be like this:

```
@given('user is logged in')  
try:  
   # MY CODE HERE  
except:  
   # GET THE STEP NAME HERE
```

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've done essentially what you are trying to do, take a screenshot of a failed test, by setting an `after_step` hook in my `environment.py` file.

```
def after_step(context, step):
    if step.status == "failed":
        take_the_shot(context.scenario.name + " " + step.name)
```

You most likely want the scenario name in there too if a step can appear in multiple scenarios.

If the above does not work for you, unfortunately behave does not set a `step` field on `context` with the current step like it does for `scenario` with the current scenario or `feature` with the current feature. You could have a `before_step` hook that performs such assignment and then in the step itself, you'd access the step's name as `context.step.name`. Something like:

```
def before_step(context, step):
    context.step = step
```

And the step implementation:

```
def step_impl(context):
    if some_condition:
        take_the_shot(context.scenario.name + " " + context.step.name)
```

Comment: **take_the_shot** is the method which contains the scenario name as parameter?